# Sums of Nilpotent Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A =$ diag$(a_1,a_2,…,a_n)$, where the sum of all $a_i$’s is zero.

Show that A is a sum of nilpotent matrices.

My idea:

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$
Where $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^2$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^2$ = $0_2$

Extending the 2 $\times$ 2 matrix, we get

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$ +  $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

Where $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^2$ =  $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^2$ = $0_4$

Kindly correct me if I’m wrong, and also, please help me how to generalized this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where and what matrix?

Answer (score 2):

The diagonal matrices of the form $\operatorname{diag}(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,-1)$ form a basis of the space of the matrices with null trace. In fact, a matrix with null trace is $\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ with $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=0$, which is equal to$$a_1\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0,\ldots,0,-1)+a_2\operatorname{diag}(0,1,0,\ldots,0,-1)+\cdots+a_{n-1}\operatorname{diag}(0,0,\ldots,0,1,-1).$$Now, you can apply your idea to each matrix of the type $\operatorname{diag}(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,-1)$.

Comment: Hi! Can you please elaborate further? I quite can't  understand. Thank you!

Comment: Do you agree that the matrices that I mentioned form a basis of the space of matrices with $0$ trace?

Comment: I can't visualise it honestly how do you right it?

Comment: @Migz I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: Thank you, it helps so much! But how can i say that the sum of matrices is nilpotent?

Comment: @Migz I never claimed that. The Idea now is to use your idea to prove that each of the diagonal matrices that I mentioned is a sum of nilpotent matrices.

Comment: @v_lentin You are right, but the remaining matrices (those with only $0$'s in the main diagonal) are linear combinations of matrices with a single non-null entry (outside the main diagonal), which are already nilpotent.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I spotted my mistake and deleted my comment.

Comment: How can I show that the diagonal matrices you mentioned are sum of nilpotent matrices?

Comment: @Migz I could answer that, but meanwhile you got [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2772246/446262).

Answer (score 1):

My answer follows @JoséCarlosSantos' post.
It is enough to notice that for all $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, $$E_{i, i} -E_{j, j} = \left(E_{i, j}\right) + \left(- E_{j, i}\right) + \left(E_{i,  i} -E_{i, j} + E_{j, i} - E_{j, j}\right)$$ and $$\left(E_{i,  i} -E_{i, j} + E_{j, i} - E_{j, j}\right)^{2} = 0$$

Comment: What is $E_{i,i}? Sorry, I'm not really knowledgeable with proving 

Comment: I use the notation: $E_{i, j} = \left(\delta_{i, k} . \delta_{j, l}\right)_{1 \leq k, l \leq n}$ where $\delta$ denotes the Kronecker's symbol, i.e $E_{i, j}$ is the matrix whose entry of indices $(i, j)$ is $1$ and whose all the other entries are $0$s.

Comment: How can I relate that with my idea? 

Comment: The matrices $E_{i, i} -E_{i, j} +E_{j, i} -E_{j, j}$ "generalize" in higher dimensions the $2$x$2$ matrix $E_{1, 1} - E_{1, 2} + E_{2, 1} -E_{2, 2} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ you used in your examples.

Comment: Does that E also mean Projection? Because in our class E was used to represent Projection.

Comment: No. For all $i \ne j$, $E_{i, j}^{2} = 0 \ne E_{i, j}$ and hence, $E_{i, j}$ does not represent any projection.

Comment: Here, the letter $E$ comes from the fact that $E_{i, j}$ is sometimes called the elementary matrix of indices $(i, j)$.

The family $\left\{ E_{i, j} : 1 \leq i, j \leq n \right\}$ is just the canonical basis of the vector space of $n$x$n$ matrices.

Comment: I see, thank you so much!